# Pentaho Connection to MultiSubnet SQL Server environment

Tags: sql, sql-server, etl, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

In Hitachi Pentaho 8.2 Data Integration (Spoon) we are trying to configure "MultisubnetFailover=True" for a SQL Server database connection. 
For database connections we are using "MS-SQL Server(Native)/Native JDBC". The problem is that I can't find where to set this property in the Database Connection component, and it doesn't look like I can specify the complete connection string for the driver to use. Where can I set this property?

It doesn't look like the Options tab is the correct place for setting this property, and I don't see a way to just specify the entire connection string myself. Also, ODBC can't work for us because the ETL changes the server and database dynamically (we use Pentaho variables to vary those) and ODBC is only one hardcoded connection.

Any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried the "Generic database" connection type? You can specify the exact JDBC connection URL you want with that with that. It might allow you to workaround the issue if the Options tab isn't giving you the desired outcome using the regular "MS SQL Server" connection type.